# How to simplify these kind of circuits?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, symmetry, electrical-resistance

[image]

All the resisters have equal resistance. What's concept of solving this kind of problems.

Comment: Closely related if not duplicate?  [Current Through a Circuit with an 8 Resistor Setup](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69409/140996)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily simplify the circuit with the rule given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform. In the most upper and lower branch you can add up the two resistors, that are in series to 2R. Then just apply the transformation rule and after you can further simplify the circuit with the common rules for a parallel and series equivalent resistor.